# Running C programs in Linux/MacOSX

Tags: c

Here is another(probably) noob question. Let us assume that I have a simple 1 file program (called myProg.c) written in C. When I want to compile this program in Linux/MacOSX, I type "gcc -o haha myProg.c". The executable file that is generated is now named "haha". When I wish to run this program, I will need to type "./haha" in the console.

What do I need to do to stop typing "./" always? How can I make sure that by just typing "haha", my program will be invoked? I have checked the permissions of the file "haha" and it is executable. Am I correct in thinking that the "./" indicates that the path of executable file i.e., the file is present in the current directory (".")??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current directory is by default not a part of PATH in unix-derived OS'es. This is a security measure, which you *can but should not* change by modifying PATH in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`

The reason not to include the current directory in path: Assume that you are root, and you have a malicious user. This user creates e.g. a `ls` executable in his home directory, which does something not nice. If you're looking at what this user is up to, and type `ls` while in his home directory, *his* ls will be executed.

If you want to just change it, add `PATH="${PATH}:."` to your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks Erik. That pretty much answers my question. Another question though. Suppose the path variable is processed by the OS in a left-to-right fashion. Can we not add the current directory "." at the end to ensure that such risky scenarios(as mentioned in the answer) do not arise? Or does the OS keep looking up in all the directories mentioned in the path and then chooses the one which is farthest away from the root directory?

Comment: @CRK: The first one found is chosen, so putting `.` last reduces the risk. It's still a problem though - what happens when you try to use e.g. `mc` which happens to not be installed on this particular system? Or you mistype `ls` as `lls`?

Comment: You can append "." to the end by doing export PATH=$PATH:.